# Different Action Bar Items (Button/Image) for each Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

Since I am new to android I am not able to figure this out.

I have an app with few layouts. I want to add Action bar on each activity with background image on action bar instead of default color and two action images one on left and one on right.

The here problem get bigger For each activity i need to alter/change image on action bar with change in action. 
I do not know using third party Action Bar such as Sherlock, Compact,
Pleas help and provide code solution link any possible help you can.

Thanks in advance

I forget to mention that i am Using (Android 2.2 Froyo as minimum SDK and Android 4.3 as Compiled as target)

Comment: You will have to use ActionBarSherlock to have an ActionBar on pre 3.0 Devices since that time there was no ActionBar.
If you want to set different Backgrounds in that Actionbar based on your current Activity i would either set the Background programmatically, or make a different subclass of your AppTheme and add a different Background to the ActionBar in every one of them. Now you just have to set these Styles in your Manifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sherlock Action Bar sample:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.some_background);
        bg.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(bg);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("some title");

        menu.add(getResources().getString(R.string.some_name))
                .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            someAction();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).setIcon(R.drawable.some_icon)
                    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        }
    }
```

You can set different action bars in each activity.